# Is it possible to move class files created to the code locations in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I am quite new to gradle, currently working on a java project where I have to migrate from ANT to Gradle. The ANT scripts compile and create .class files at the java code location itself. While In Gradle it stores all output class files in build/classes directory. Is it possible to create class files at the code location in Gradle? I was thinking that would make the migration a bit easy for me to follow. If it is not possible, is there a reason why Gradle uses separate output folder? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly configure Gradle to however you like. For example, to change the output of the `compileJava` task, you would change [`destinationDirectory`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile:destinationDirectory) property.

Gradle has a dedicated guide on migrating from ANT to Gradle: [Migrating Builds From Apache Ant](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_ant.html)

> is there a reason why Gradle uses separate output folder?

Well, it is a different build tool, but mainly because it is by convention. Both Maven and Gradle follow this convention and it is well established.

Comment: Thanks. For instance, changing destinationDirectory to a directory named "src/gen", the class files will be created within src/gen/classes, right? 
I am looking for a scenario where the class files are created in the same location as the java files. 



.
Just to clarify,
if we have a java scr/main/java/packageName/test.java, we  need to generate the class path in the same location as scr/main/java/packageName/test.class